# Initialize program correctly using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been dabbling with MVVM. In fact, I've religiously *tried* to follow it's rules and best practices.

How is program initialization handled properly?

Specifically, I am confused as to why you would call the view (from the App.xaml) first.

My assumptions has been, that a controller still owns the abstraction of the view (ViewModel) and uses it to update the view. (I prefer to separate presentation and processing into different classes, which I guess would make this "MVVMC").
So in my eyes, the view should not be the first thing to be initialized.
This being said, my solution has been to start the controller from the app.xaml code-behind and pass the ViewModel to the controller.

Even though I get a nice information pipline, I have the feeling that this is not the correct way, since I am still using the app.xaml code-behind.

**This is what my application looks like:**

[image]

So, what is the best/most-efficient/most-accepted way to initialize an application?

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection ...except for the problem of too many layers of indirection"

Comment: @ASh could you clarify? Are you referring to the separation of ViewModel and controller?

Comment: @Esguio, you propably have *very important* reason to create controller between model and viewmodel in mvvm achitecture

Comment: Well, I would argue, that as a project grows the separation between processing and presentation becomes very important, specially when multiple views/viewmodels are in play. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Esguio: Actually no. As a project grows bigger, the complexity of the project grows equally, whether you have tightly or loosely coupled Views to ViewModels. Much more important is to avoid circular dependencies, have exactly one View per ViewModel and vice versa, etc

Comment: @Liero Sure the project becomes complexer as it grows and my rational is: if you can separate the presentation logic from the processing, why wouldn't you?
I mean if the alternative is to have the viewmodel do presentation logic and input processing, I'd much rather stick to using a controller that uses the viewmodel to do the presentation. Specially for bigger projects.

Comment: Yeah, but that's what VM is for. Your diagram suggest, that you have ill defined responsibilities, but that would be judging too quickly. Model = data access and business logic (in your case probably processing). View = presentation of data and application logic. Responsibility of VM is to expose data and business logic to a View is such way, that is easily consumable from view, e.g. through binding.

Comment: So you are saying that processing should be delegated to the model, but why not just create a class that is responsible for this? Otherwise this becomes MVC, and where one class is basically responsible for everything. I would go even further and separate data access from the model using the repository pattern. So the models really only store the state of the data

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MVVM isn't a very strict ruleset and it definitely leaves space for a wide variety of flavors.

Based on whether View or ViewModel is instantiated first, you can differenciate two aproaches:

1. **ViewModel first** approach, where instance of ViewModel is created first and then typically based on some convention a View is selected. DataTemplateSelector is a good example.
2. **View first** approach, where view is created first (typically a Window or UserControl) and using some convention view is selected. It might be a responsibility of a View to create a ViewModel instance for itself, or it might be delegated to somebody else.

When it comes to initialization, it must always be done in app.xaml resp app.xaml.cs as it is the entry point for your app. You also must realize, the application process is
bound to the Dispatcher loop. When the last Window in your app is closed, dispatcher loops ends and the application process exits. The last window is typically the MainWindow.

Also, take the application startup time into account. You want to display some Window as soon as possible. So if you want to do any logic before the Window is shows, make sure you don't do any I/O, database or API calls, etc.

I typically have Bootstrapper.cs class that I invoke from App.xaml.cs. It's responsibility is to setup IoC and display the UI. It might be a loading window and then MainWindow.

In Bootstrapper.cs you might create instance of MainWindowViewModel first, the create MainWindow and assign the ViewModel to it's DataContext, or you might just create MainWindow and leave the ViewModel creation up to the MainWindow itself. I tend to do the latter.

There is nothing wrong with either of the approaches and neither violates the MVVM principle.

My biggest recommendation to you is - if you can't decide between two or more options, choose the simpler. Or in other words, don't complicate things unless you have very good reason to. KISS